# Calendar Pro - How to config to use src path not in extensible-all-debug

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I using `extensible-1.5.1` and i run app in

`extensible-1.5.1/examples/calendar/TestApp/test-app.html`

I try to custom `Event` Form window by add a new `textfield` into this form. Here is form default

[image]

But i can't find file to edit.

I think that in `extensible-1.5.1\src\calendar\form\EventWindow.js`. But when i remove `src` folder then project still working and nothing change?

How to do that thanks

**Edit**
I found that in `extensible-all-debug.js` file. But that file is really complex

How to config to use data in `extensible-1.5.1\src\` like `calendar` at extjs example

Answer (score 5):

You are correct in that the class you need to use is `Extensible.calendar.form.EventWindow`.  However, instead of editing that file, you should extend that class and make your own version of it.  You can use that file as a guide, and override the `getFormItemConfigs` function to modify the form as you need it:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.EventWindow", {
    extend: "Extensible.calendar.form.EventWindow",
    modal: true,
    enableEditDetails: false,

    initComponent: function()
    {
        this.callParent();
    },

    getFormItemConfigs: function() {
        var items = [/*your form items here */];

        return items;
    },
    //... other stuff here maybe...
});
```

Then, you can override the `Extensible.calendar.view.AbstractCalendar` to use the class you just made:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.AbstractCalendarOverride", {
    override: 'Extensible.calendar.view.AbstractCalendar',

    getEventEditor : function()
    {
        this.editWin = this.ownerCalendarPanel.editWin;

        if(!this.editWin)
        {
            //Change this line:
            this.ownerCalendarPanel.editWin = Ext.create('MyApp.view.EventWindow', {
                id: 'ext-cal-editwin',
                calendarStore: this.calendarStore,
                modal: this.editModal,
                enableEditDetails: this.enableEditDetails,
                listeners: {
                    'eventadd': {
                        fn: function(win, rec, animTarget) {
                            //win.hide(animTarget);
                            win.currentView.onEventAdd(null, rec);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                    'eventupdate': {
                        fn: function(win, rec, animTarget) {
                            //win.hide(animTarget);
                            win.currentView.onEventUpdate(null, rec);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                    'eventdelete': {
                        fn: function(win, rec, animTarget) {
                            //win.hide(animTarget);
                            win.currentView.onEventDelete(null, rec);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                    'editdetails': {
                        fn: function(win, rec, animTarget, view) {
                            // explicitly do not animate the hide when switching to detail
                            // view as it looks weird visually
                            win.animateTarget = null;
                            win.hide();
                            win.currentView.fireEvent('editdetails', win.currentView, rec);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                    'eventcancel': {
                        fn: function(win, rec, animTarget){
                            this.dismissEventEditor(null, animTarget);
                            win.currentView.onEventCancel();
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // allows the window to reference the current scope in its callbacks
        this.editWin.currentView = this;
        return this.editWin;
    }
});
```

This may not give you exactly what you need, but hopefully it puts you on the right track.